# Rounding only left side of UIButton without removing uieffect

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I have two uibuttons that a right next to eachother. I would like to make them look joined by giving the left button rounded top left and bottom left corners and the right button top right and bottom right corners.

I have seen several solutions to this but all I have seen break the uieffectview I have behind the button.

Comment: Have you tried the segment control?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
UIBezierPath *maskPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.viewOutlet.bounds byRoundingCorners:(UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerBottomLeft | UIRectCornerBottomRight) cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(10.0, 10.0)];

CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
maskLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
maskLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
self.viewOutlet.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

[image]

**Update:**
If You need border just create another `CAShapeLayer` and add it to view's layer as sublayer. Like this (place this code below upper code):

```
CAShapeLayer *borderLayer = [[CAShapeLayer alloc] init];
borderLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
borderLayer.path  = maskPath.CGPath;
borderLayer.lineWidth   = 4.0f;
borderLayer.strokeColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
borderLayer.fillColor   = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;

[self.viewOutlet.layer addSublayer:borderLayer];
```

[image]